# Can Selenium WebDriver automate native windows based pop-ups?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, window

I was asked this question recently(How to handle window based pop ups) and i replied with the traditional answer involving third party tools like Auto It to which the interviewer replied "Selenium has advanced much and this is outdated answer".

Does the new feature in selenium4 "switchTo(WINDOW.TYPE)" cater to above scenario?

Any links/info/explanation is cordially appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the popups' content is also window based (like file upload dialog, print dialog), I think that Selenium may not support it, windows application automation library has to be involved like autoit, pywinauto and others.

Comment: Thanks for the response,Robin. Even i have the same idea.